# How do I link data objects in an Array to the DOM elements created based on that Array

Tags: reactjs

I have an Array of Objects that is created dynamically and I use that Array to create a set of DOM elements on the page.

```
{
   DUMMY_DATA.map(
      i => <div>{i.value}</div>
   )
}
```

This Array is used in several places and other components alter the properties of the Objects stored within it. If, say, the Object at index 3 is altered how can I best get the DOM element, from my list described above, that represents that data Object?

Hopefully the below example will illustrate better than my sketchy description.
In this example the `DUMMY_DATA` Array is passed to a child component that uses it to create a scrollable list of DOM elements. If you click one of the items in the list it will scroll to the top.
The button beside the list selects a random index on `DUMMY_DATA`. With only that index as a reference how can I then trigger the list component to scroll to the relevant DOM element, as it does when the list item itself is clicked?

[image: Edit angry-wilson-d4fhk4]